# RESTful way to deal with multi-step "new" action in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an application that requires a 2-step process for creating an object for one of the models.

I have considered...

creating a custom route to the custom "new" action

or

using the same "new" action for both steps but render the correct view based on a param

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this screencast for a multistep form.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Ryanb is using a nice way with the validations for each step and keeping everything in the create action so no need to have extra routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for wizard kind of a solution this might worth looking at

https://github.com/jeffp/wizardly

But I'm not sure about Rails3 support.