# Implementing a multi-step "new" action with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

What's the best way to implement the `new` action on a resource where there are multiple steps involved, with Next buttons? In my case I need the user to enter the type of Post they are making, such as text, image, audio, etc, and then when they click Next I show a form to upload the media (text posts will show a normal Create button, controlled via Javascript).

I'm looking for something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900414/restful-way-to-deal-with-multi-step-new-action-in-rails-3), but I need some clarity for how to do this with Active Admin. I'm thinking I need to do something like,

```
controller do
  def create
    if need_more_info?
      prepare_and_set_vars_for_partial_to_use
      render "new"
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Doing just that doesn't work though (in my case the `posts` resource is a nested resource too).

The contents of the form itself is implemented by a partial instead of the resource DSL. I just want to call it 'again' and pass some new parameters to the template.

Comment: In practice, I've found it easier to make one giant form with every possible input needed and then use JavaScript to keep track of the current step and show/hide the relevant inputs.

Comment: I do that for all the other attributes actually, but I need to generate a pre-signed form for Amazon S3, and I want to do that in a separate step after I've determined the type of media.

Comment: I would create a collection action that handles the signing. Fire off an ajax request after the user has selected the media type, and then update and reveal the form.